# How do I get docker COPY to copy a directory and not just its contents?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile, can I copy a directory from my host machine to my image while preserving the directory itself?

When using COPY (or ADD), The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) mentions

> The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

But it doesn't mention a way to preserve the directory when desired.

Do I have to put a RUN command prior to the COPY and explicitly `mkdir` the directory first?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly preserve the directory, however, you can specify the target directory and give it the same name as the copied directory like so.

`COPY ./host_machine_path/dir_to_copy ./container_path/dir_to_copy/`

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> If <dest> doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.